# Differentiate between fetch fail for timeout or for offline

Tags: react-native

In react native, I am doing a fetch like this:

```
let res;

try {
   res = fetch('https://ggh/api/network');
} catch(ex) {
   console.log('ex:', ex);
}
```

Gives the same `ex` for automatic timeout, and also for if offline. For the url `https://ggh/api/network` it is for sure a timeout error.

I purposely don't do a promise with a preset timeout of like 10sec because I want the native system to decide when its good to timeout. Is this correct assumption? Or is there a default timeout?

I was trying to differentiate between the two. Here were ideas I had but didn't like them:

1. On error, use `NetInfo` and/or `fetch('https://www.google.com/')` to figure out if is really offline ELSE original fetch was a timeout

   - The problem with this second fetch is, if timeout is due to really bad net connectivity, user will have to wait double time - for two things to timeout
   - problem with NetInfo I hear its not accurate and must always do a fetch to verify it
2. If there is a default timeout for react-native fetch, I can test how long the call took, and then mark it as timeout ELSE offline.

Does anyone have any other sure fire ideas?